# Android Studio is picking up versionCode from Manifest of Library Project and not my Manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest, android-version

I am porting my app to Android Studio and came across this problem that the version code that the APK is being detected (when uploading to Google Play) is `1` from the Manifest file of the library project (`circularImageView`). My actual app is named `app` below.

[image]

When I try to upload the app to Google Play, it says that my versionCode = 1 (see screenshot below):
[image]

See below for the versionCode in actually my app which is `58`.
[image]

Comment: It's not possible. Android studio always get version from your project `build.gradle` file

Comment: aah I see, so I need to change the versionCode in build.gradle also. Let me try that quick but you are right i think too. WIll report back in a few minutes, add your comment as answer and I will mark it as answer once i get it working. I am just coming from Eclipse so getting used to the gradle stuff.

Answer (score 4):

**Android studio** always get version from your project `build.gradle` file

**See the below snap:** in `Android Studio build.gradle`

[image]

Comment: wont let me mark as answer for another 9mins, too late here .. will do this in the morning.

Comment: @user1406716 Ok don't worry. but is your problem solved?

Comment: yes, just havent been familiar with Android Studio so had this confusion. So should I updating version number in Manifest **AND** `build.gradle` every time it needs to be incremented or does the Manifest does not matter at all?

Comment: Delete the values in manifest to avoid confusion, they are overriden by those in build.gradle.

Comment: @user1406716 here in Android Studio `manifest.xml` used only for registering your activities, permissions and components etc... and `build.gradle` used for `apk` built control `(flavors, variants, etc)` seprately.

Answer (score 0):

Change Code version in `build.gradle` of your app. Android studio combine Manifest at run. I think if you don't mention codeVersion in `build.gradle` then it pick version from Manifest generated after combining of all projects.